# How do I install BeautifulSoup in Python2.7.12 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, pip

I have installed beautifulsoup using `pip install beautifulsoup4`
But when I enter `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`
it's showing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 314, in <module>
    from . import _html5lib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py", line 70, in <module>
    class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_base'
```

What should I do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170902/error-importing-beautifulsoup-conflict-with-python-version

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but beautifulsoup needs a different version for python2.7 than it does for python3.6.  bs4 is for python 3.6 and bs3 is for python2.7.

Comment: As of July 2019, bs3 has become obsolete and replaced with bs4 (https://pypi.org/project/BeautifulSoup/)